# Where are iTunes smart playlists stored on disk?

Tags: itunes, playlist, smart-playlist

I want to create a *Best albums* smart playlist containing a *somewhat reasonable* number of songs :

- the rule `Album rating` `is greater than` `★★★` result in a 221 songs playlist.
- wheareas the rule `Album rating` `is greater than` `★★` result in a 4000+ songs playlist.

I understand why those numbers, but still I would prefer that the resulting playlist contains ~1000 songs : hence my need to have access to the smart playlist file definition so I can overwrite the ratings representation inside.

*Other approach tried : [activate half star ratings](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/itunes-half-star-rating/) (to create a 'greater than 3.5 stars' rule), but if half star is activated for song rating in the main window, it is not the case for the smart playlist dialog.*

Comment: Based on which criteria do you want to limit the number of songs down to 1000?

Comment: @patrix the album rating. For eg if in the underlying smart playlist xml file there is *<albumRatingMin>3</albumRatingMin>* I would edit it to 3.5 and see how many tracks pass that threshold, and adjust the value accordingly

Comment: The definition is stored in `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml` (big file, search for the name of the smart list). The playlist definition seems to be stored as binary data though...

Answer (score 1):

In the smart playlist edit panel, just specify a max limit for the number of songs (eg: max 1,000 songs or max 4GB), and also choose that it should choose the highest rated songs to reach that limit.

Comment: If I do that then selected albums are deprived of their lowest rated songs. I want albums to be full. Too bad there is not a "Limit N items selected by highest album rating" option.

Comment: @kraymer if you're on a mac you could create an applescript or perhaps automator script to create a playlist. That would allow you to make it choose entire albums.